# Durables using SoapUI and Hermes

Tags: jms, soapui, tibco-ems

We are facing a major problem with soapui when using with Hermes JMS. When we send a message over a queue and expects to receive response on a topic, SoapUi will create a durable subscription. These durables are maintained after couple of months and causing a major problem.

Can any one suggest a way to remove these durable subscriptions, or suggest a way to create non-durable subscriptions?

I might also mention that we are using Tibco EMS...

Thanks!